# Does tensorflow support python 2.7 on windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tensorflow

OS:Windows 10
Python ver.:Python 2.7.13
tensorflow ver.:1.0.1 
CUDA:v8.0
cudnn:v5.1
I have already set my CUDA and cudnn well.

cudnn64_5.dll is in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin`
cudnn.h is in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include`
cudnn.lib is in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64`
and added path:`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin`

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable(x64) is also installed.

but still got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras import*
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I found that there is very little information about tensorflow for python2.7 on Windows.
Is there any other solution?
Or should I switch to python 3.5.x on Windows?
Or use python2.7 on Linux?

Comment: You should ideally be writing Python3 nowadays, anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows):

> TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows.

Comment: But how come they support python 2.7 on linux and mac but only skip Windows. I had read the docs many times.They only omit python 2.7 on Windows. QAQ